# How to get a drive item using Graph SDK 5.0

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am in the process of upgrading to Graph SDK 5.0 and I have the following request

```
request = graphClient
    .Users[userId]
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Items[itemId]
    .Request();
```

The issue is that ".Drives" does not have access to ".Items". How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#drive-item-paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SDK v5 you can access drive items this way.

```
var driveItem = await _client
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Items[itemId]
    .GetAsync();
```